# TextView background change with selector

Tags: android, textview

Trying to color `TextView` background when it gets mouse manipulation with help of selector:

Content of `selector2.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</selector>
```

`TextView` in layout file:

```
            <TextView
                android:background="@drawable/selector2"
                android:textColor="@color/color_mk_white"
                android:text="Temperature"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                ></TextView>
```

I'm getting `TextView` with blue background when program starts and it doesn't reacts on mouse  clicking. How to get background color change when it gets mouse actions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you deep dive into the android code and see the code for TextView, it does not implement **Checkable** interface where as if you see the Code for Radio Button, Chip etc then they implement **Checkable interface**. Now to achieve this Behaviour I did something similar by making a FrameLayout that is checkable.

***ChekableFrameLayout***

```
public class CheckableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
private boolean mChecked = false;
public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    mChecked = checked;
    refreshDrawableState();
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}

private static final int[] CheckedStateSet = {
        android.R.attr.state_checked,
};

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (isChecked()) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CheckedStateSet);
    }
    return drawableState;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    toggle();
    return super.performClick();
}}
```

Now after writing this code I used it in my Xml as follows:

```
 <com.example.CheckableFrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/chipsSelectedDay"
android:layout_width="65dp"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:background="@drawable/checked_unchecked_drawable"
android:clickable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingVertical="11dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#838D99"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Sun" /></com.example.CheckableFrameLayout>
```

And for the background checked_unchecked_drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/consultme_slot_selected_drawable_bg"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/consultme_slot_unselected_drawable_bg"/>
</selector>
```

Now using this CheckableFrameLayout we can achieve the desired property. You can do the same for Textview. But I had to implement this because I had to create a Layout with two line of text each having different style and Chip doesn't allow multiline text.
But seeing you use case I guess you should go for Chip implementation. Anyways Hope this solution helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select/deselect on click (and change background color respectively), you can do something like this:

```
yourView.setOnClickListener { view ->
    view.isSelected = !view.isSelected
    //other logic
}
```

Also, you may want to place `state_pressed` above `state_selected`. This arrangement ensures that the color changes when the view is pressed even when it's already in the 'selected' state.